# How can I create a Yocto meta-layer that uses two toolchains?

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto

I need to compile u-boot for my machine which is a 64 bits arm core with a 32-bit toolchain. The problem is that all 
my other recip‪es use the 64 bits linaro toolchain. How can a tell bitbake to use the 32-bit linaro for the u-boot?

I've tried to add in my u-boot recipe things like:

```
UBOOT_ARCH = "arm"
PACKAGE_ARCH = "armv7a"
CROSS_COMPILE="arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-"
```

but nothing seems to work. It continues using `aarch64-poky-linux-gcc` to compile u-boot. My recipe at the moment looks like this:

```
DESCRIPTION = "U-boot for mymachine"
require recipes-bsp/u-boot/u-boot.inc
LICENSE = "GPLv2"

COMPATIBLE_MACHINE = "mymachine"
UBOOT_MACHINE_mymachine = "mymachine_config"
UBOOT_ARCH_mymachine = "arm"
PACKAGE_ARCH = "armv7a"
CROSS_COMPILE="arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/mymachine/u-boot-mymachine.git;branch=master \
       file://boot.cmd"

SRCREV="${AUTOREV}"
PV = "v2016.03"
(...)
```

My `machine.conf` has:

```
require conf/machine/include/arm64/arch-armv8.inc
```

Comment: Question already asked here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36922882/using-armhf-as-a-secondary-toolchain-in-yocto

Comment: Thx for this. I'm also working in a layer for pine64.